# cron: send email to different address in case of failure

Tags: linux, email, bash, scripting, cron

I've a cronjob like this:

```
MAILTO=mymail@mydomain.com
30 00 * * * root /run/this/script.sh
```

is there a way to tell cron to send mail to different mail addresses based on exit code? I mean, can cron send an email to allok@mydomain.com in case script.sh return 0 or send to error@mydomain.com in case something gone wrong? Or I have to do it in a wrapper script?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to do it in a wrapper script.

Answer (score 1):

No, cron send all output to the specified user.

Normally all cron jobs should have STDOUT redirected to /dev/null, because you don't want to spam the user with all cron jobs that run on the server.

If you would do this (the redirect), you will get the email only in case of failures.

Comment: This assumes that the command/script in the job prints *some* output to `stderr`, no?

Comment: It also assumes that the command/script doesn't print any output to stderr on success, either

Comment: Yes, on both accounts

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://cronitor.io. It can send you alerts if your job fails. You write your cron command like this:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/my_cron_job.sh || curl https://cronitor.link/d3x0/fail
```

You can also ping a /complete endpoint to indicate success and you can make a rule like "Alert me if i haven't had a success /complete ping in 24 hours."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Just add **> /dev/null** after your CRON script.

`MAILTO="mymail@mydomain.com"
30 00 * * * root /run/this/script.sh > /dev/null`

Comment: this assumes the script prints something to stderr, and also requires setup of an SMTP host with something like `ssmtp`, which integrates automatically with `mailutils`

Comment: it also assumes that the script doesn't log to stderr during a successful execution