# Get email notification from crontab if the cron doesn't run/return a non zero exit code

Tags: linux, cron

I want to use MAILTO to send email notifications *only* on unsuccessful runs of crons

- It does not run at all
- Results in a non zero exit code

I have read that email notifications are sent to the default user but how can I filter them only for these specific scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

cron sends an email when the program prints any output. You can use that either by having your script providing the error just as plain text, or you can use something like this:

```
/path/to/your/script.sh || echo "script error"
```

This will output `script error` if the script returns with an error code. Printing errors directly in the script will however allow you to provide more details about the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, couple of clarifications here, in the example that you have shared will the `echo "script error"` be executed in case of a failed run of `script.sh`? Also, where exactly do we use the mailto utility here. I'm not very clear with this/

Comment: Would this be something like 
`<scheduling configs> /path/to/your/script.sh || echo "script error" |mail -s "Subject of Mail" someother@address.com`

Comment: You don't have to pipe this into mail. Cron usually sends mails automatically. You [may have to set the recipient address](https://serverfault.com/questions/734850/cron-send-email-to-different-address-in-case-of-failure).